# How do I create a rails controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action

My rails app has a single CustomerSelectionController, with two actions:

index: which shows a form where the user can enter customer information and
select: which just displays a static page.

```
class CustomerSelectionController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def select
  end
end
```

I've created an entry in my routes.rb file:

```
  resources :customer_selection
```

and the form in the index view looks like:

```
<h1>Customer Selection</h1>

<%= form_tag("customer_selection/select", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= submit_tag("Select") %>
<% end %>
```

however when I click on the Select button in the browser, all I get is:

Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for CustomerSelectionController

I'm not sure why it is trying to perform an action called show? I haven't defined or referenced one anywhere.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Did you route customer_selection/select to that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure why it is trying to perform an action called show?  I haven't defined or referenced one anywhere.

Yes you have. That's what `resources` does. It defines the seven default RESTful routes: index, show, new, create, edit, update and destroy. When you route to `/customer_selection/select`, the route that matches is "/customer_action/:id", or the "show" route. Rails instantiates your controller and attempts to invoke the "show" action on it, passing in an ID of "select".

If you want to add a route in addition to those, you need to explicitly define it, and you should also explicitly state which routes you want if you don't want all seven:

```
resources :customer_selection, only: %w(index) do
  collection { get :select }
  # or
  # get :select, on: :collection
end
```

Since you have so few routes, you can also just define them without using `resources`:

```
get "/customer_selection" => "customer_selection#index"
get "/customer_select/select"
```

Note that, in the second route, the `"customer_select#select"` is implied. In a route with only two segments, Rails will default to "/:controller/:action" if you don't specify a controller/action.

Comment: Can I just drop the resources line then, and let convention-over-configuration take over?

Comment: No, you still need to define a route. You don't *have* to use `resources` though, see my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, where can I get a concise explanation of that code block?

Comment: Cool, I like your second option better. I can read it. Thanks.

Comment: The Rails routing guide, as linked in the comments to your question: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Rather than tell me you like it, you should upvote and/or accept the answer to mark your question as answered.

Comment: Will do. I think though that the second 'get' should be get "/customer_selection/select".